# React undefined state

Tags: reactjs

I just begin with react, i want to display cards from state :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import personnages from './personnages';
import ChampRecherche from '../components/champrecherche';

class Cards extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataFromChild:null
        }
    }
    getVal = (dataFromChild) => {
        this.setState({ dataFromChild : dataFromChild })
    }
    listItems = personnages.map((perso) => {
        
        return <li style={{ display: perso.title.indexOf(this.state.dataFromChild) !== -1 ? 'block' : 'none' }} key={perso.id}>{perso.title}</li>  
    });
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ChampRecherche callbackFromParent={this.getVal} />
                <ul>{this.listItems}</ul>
            </div>
        )  
    }
}

export default Cards;
```

I want to display block or none cards dynamically from a state, with code above i get an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataFromChild' of undefined
```

Could someone explains me a bit please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`listItems` does not have access to `this.state` since it's not binded to the class object. That's why you're having that error. I'll suggest you make `listItems` a class function that returns what you need to map. something like `listItems = () => personAges.map...` Hope that solves your issue. Or you could `bind` as suggested by other answers.

Comment: Hi, good point, you mean : this.listItems = this.listItems.bind(this); ?

Comment: could you explain me please about making listItems as a class?

Comment: using this es6 syntax, `listItems = () => personAges.map...` javaScript performs `lexical binding` of `listItems` as a class function to your component. You could check more on JavaScript  classes

Comment: I created a class ListItems inside i have the listItems = () personnages.map ... and render an <ul>{ this.listItems }</ul>
On main class i exported i render <ListItems item={this.state.dataFromChild} />, so now how can i make operation to display none or block depending of this.state.dataFromChild ?

Comment: change your `listitem` to be a function like this: `listItems = () => personnages.map((perso) =>  <li style={{ display: perso.title.indexOf(this.state.dataFromChild) !== -1 ? 'block' : 'none' }} key={perso.id}>{perso.title}</li>);` then where you typed `{this.listItems}` change it to `{this.listItems()}`

Comment: Hey, thank you, but this.state is undefined inside listItems function because this is an arrow function so the 'this' is in listItems function scope ? i'm wrong?

Comment: `this` in that arrow function should refer to the `class object` But if you're having issues, you can `bind` manually in your `constructor` using `this.listItems = this.listItems.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind. In the constructor:

```
 this.listItems = this.listItems.bind(this)
```

Or when you call it:

```
this.listItems.bind(this)
```

In addition, you need to check the value as the other answer explains.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response but how i get state to display or not listitems?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The error that you get is because 'this' instead listitems is different from the class state. When you write {this. Listitems.bind(this)} the problem is solved.

Comment: In addition you need to check, as the other answer explains, if this.state.dataFromChild is already set or whether it is still null.